# WCF/C# Passed value is different from submission

Tags: c#, linq, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a C# console app that uses WCF data services an LINQ.
Some of my crud processes are not working, I have managed to figure out why the code is failing with some help but I have no idea how to fix it.

The value that I pass to the method always seems to turn out as 0 when I am using the debugger. I am trying to delete a record using an ID set by a variable in the console application.

here is the data contract:

```
    [OperationContract]
    void DeleteRecord(int vehicleIDDel);
```

Here is the service:

```
public void DeleteRecord(int vehicleIDDel)
    {

        VehicleStockItem vehicle =
         (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
          where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleIDDel
          select v)
          .FirstOrDefault();

        db.VehicleStockItems.Remove(vehicle);
        db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

Here is the code from the service consumer:

```
        Console.Write("Enter ID of Vehicle to delete: ");
        int vehicleIDDel = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        vehicleRef.DeleteRecord(vehicleIDDel);
        Console.Write("Successfully deleted record #" + vehicleIDDel + ".\nPress enter to continue");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And here is the error that occurs when I try delete a record using the console app using ID 16 for example:

[image: Variable is always 0]

Here you can see that vehicleIDDel is set as 0 even though I passed the variable as 16 from the console app. Why is it appearing as 0 on my service even though that's not what I'm sending? The service works fine using  the test client and setting the variables in that.

Comment: What value does it go when the breakpoint hits the line `vehicleRef.DeleteRecord(vehicleIDDel);`?? . If 16 is sent and if it's not received at the service, then the value breaks in the proxy.

Comment: @Turbulence vehicleRef.DeleteRecord(vehicleIDDel); = 16 before it is passed over. Any ideas?

Comment: can you update the service reference and check if you would have modified the service and havn't updated the consumer client

Comment: This fixed it. I love you but at the same time I feel like crying right now. So much wasted time.. I should of tried this first!!

Comment: Ha ha..I doubted it should be a mistake at updating the service reference the moment you said it worked in your Test client. So, the ultimate check would be at the proxy.

Comment: Post an answer and I'll accept it so you gain some rep

Answer (score 0):

There is no such big issue in your snippet. if there is no match is found then your query returns `null`, and removing of null from a list is not allowed that's the reason for that error. you can avoid that by code like the following:

```
    VehicleStockItem vehicle =
     (from v in db.VehicleStockItems
      where v.VehicleStockItemID == vehicleIDDel
      select v)
      .FirstOrDefault();
    if(vehicle!=null){
       db.VehicleStockItems.Remove(vehicle);
    db.SaveChanges();}
  // means allow to remove from the list only if the value of`vehicle` is not null
```

Comment: No. His question was that the value `vehicleIDDel is 0` instead of 16.